# Webhook Ms Graph to listen group conversation

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to create a subscription to listen to the conversations of a group

**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions**

```
{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-96.sa.ngrok.io/api/GraphNotificationHook",
   "resource": "groups('ddhdhdnn-9999-2222-3333-b244335ce9')/conversations",
   "expirationDateTime":"2023-02-27T16:44:38.975Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValuexxeddd5582"
}
```

I am following the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIvo8.jpg)

These are the permissions that my App Registration:

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJAKd.png)

But, I have the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Subscription to a group's 'conversations' is not supported with Application-level permissions."
    }
}
```

I have reviewed several times and I cannot locate what I may be missing or what I am doing wrong. Please help me find the problem.

I was applying several permissions to the application registration as you can see in the image that I have attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your screenshot and documentation, application permission is not supported for this API call. You will have to use Delegated permission which means a true logged in user must get an access token and make this API call.

[image]

I would start by cleaning up the permissions on the app registration and remove all application permissions and client secrets created for this API call.

The only permission needed in this case is the Delegated Group.Read.All.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to create a background app that gets this data automatically and must request an access token as a logged in user before making the API call.

Comment: Hi,I have proceeded to use an "App Registration".I have only configured the delegated permission "Group.Read.All". I created a new "client secret" to obtain the token. I made the subscription API call again, but now I'm getting the following message: "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.]". I cannot understand the reason for the message. I have assigned the delegated permission "Group.Read.All" as indicated in the documentation. Could you give me a clue as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: That is because you cannot go the client secret route of getting an access token. You will need to use the code auth flow as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user